# Convert a String to JS Date

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert a string value into a JavaScript Date format but I don't seem to find a simple way to do it without having to use additional library such as datejs

```
var dateString = "20131120";
    var date       = new Date(dateString);
console.log(date);
     // I need to add an additional day to the original string
    var newDate    = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-' + (date.getDate()+1);
console.log(newDate);
```

Any hints are much appreciated.

Comment: Well, that doesn't look like a common recognicable date format. Split it into Y/M/D parts and pass them distinctly

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for your info. I don't have control over the output and cannot change the format of it!

Comment: If it's an option, I'd recommend using a library like moment.js or date.js rather than working directly with Date.

Comment: you want to convert just date??

Comment: @digitup, "output" probably means something else than you think. :) And just modify the input.

Comment: @ivarni: I prefer not to use a plugin cause it can be a performance issue and we need to avoid having heavy js files and additional server requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before ES5, parsing of date strings was entirely implementation dependent. Now [a version of ISO8601](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) has been specified, but it isn't supported by all browsers in use. So the best way is to manually parse it.

So in this case I'd do:

```
var dateString = "20131120";
var m = dateString.match(/\d\d/g);
var date = new Date(m[0] + m[1], --m[2], m[3]);
```

which will work in any browser in use that supports javascript.

Comment: That is working perfectly. Have never seen such a solution before.

Comment: It's the same as Bhavik's, but uses *match* instead of *substring* (so I gave him a +1).

Comment: Thank you very much +1 for the browsers support

Answer (score 5):

Can you please try this code

```
 var dateString  = "20131120";
    var year        = dateString.substring(0,4);
    var month       = dateString.substring(4,6);
    var day         = dateString.substring(6,8);
    var date        = new Date(year, month-1, day);
```

Here just used the simple substring method

```
First (0,4) will extract the year then next two is for month and next two is for day of month

  NOTE:
    Here we doing  `month-1` because it will count from 0 e.g (january==0).
```

hope it helps

Comment: +1 for not using additional libraries, n basic substring func for extracting date.

Answer (score 3):

Simple reg expression:

```
new Date("20131120".replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/,"$2/$3/$1"))
```

It is very basic regular expression.

Match 4 numbers, Match 2 numbers, Match 2 numbers in groups.

The replace works by using the groups $1 is the first match, $2 is the second match, $3 is the third match. Learn about regular expressions.

Comment: This seems to be working well. Testing. I am curious to know what is going on in this regex? can you please explain a bit?

Comment: added explanation above like you asked.

Comment: I really appreciate that, now I think it will not be fair not to choose this as an answer. Are you aware of any browser incompatibility for this solution ?

Comment: Let me tell you; I have been trying to get my head around the RegEx since years and I still have a long mile to go :-) Learning new stuff everyday. Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge

Answer (score -2):

The best you can do is use the ISO format: YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

For example:
new Date('2011-04-11')

or

new Date('2011-04-11T11:51:00')

For more Info: [MDN | Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

For old Internet Explorer compatibility (IE versions less than 9 do not support ISO format in Date constructor), you should split datetime string representation to it's parts and then you can use constructor using datetime parts, e.g.: new Date('2011', '04' - 1, '11', '11', '51', '00')

Note that the number of the month must be 1 less.